# MSXMLWriter60 doesn't output byteOrderMark for UTF-16 encoding

Tags: xml, vba, vb6, utf-16, byte-order-mark

I'm using a variant on code seen in ["How to make XMLDOMDocument include the XML Declaration?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144015/how-to-make-xmldomdocument-include-the-xml-declaration) (which can also be seen at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753769%28VS.85%29.aspx). If I change the encoding to "UTF-16" one would think it would output as UTF-16... and it "does"... by looking at the output in a text editor; but checking it in a hex editor, the byte-order mark is missing (despite the property being set to true), and XML editors reject the document as invalid UTF-16, for the missing BOM.

What am I overlooking?

```
'' # Create and load a DOMDocument object.

Dim xmlDoc As New DOMDocument60
xmlDoc.loadXML("<doc><one>test1</one><two>test2</two></doc>")

'' # Set properties on the XML writer - including BOM, XML declaration and encoding

Dim wrt As New MXXMLWriter60
wrt.byteOrderMark = True
wrt.omitXMLDeclaration = False
wrt.encoding = "UTF-16"
wrt.indent = False

'' # Set the XML writer to the SAX content handler.

Dim rdr As New SAXXMLReader60
Set rdr.contentHandler = wrt
Set rdr.dtdHandler = wrt
Set rdr.errorHandler = wrt
rdr.putProperty "http://xml.org/sax/properties/lexical-handler", wrt
rdr.putProperty "http://xml.org/sax/properties/declaration-handler", wrt

'' # Now pass the DOM through the SAX handler, and it will call the writer

rdr.parse xmlDoc

'' # Let the writer do its thing

Dim iFileNo As Integer
iFileNo = FreeFile
Open App.Path + "\saved.xml" For Output As #iFileNo
Print #iFileNo, wrt.output
Close #iFileNo
```

The output looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" standalone="no"?>
<doc><one>test1</one><two>test2</two></doc>
```

---

Why am I using VB6? It's actually in VBA (same generation, slight subset of VB6), used as the scripting-language for EMC-Captiva's InputAccel/FormWare, so switching is not an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when you retrieve a value from the writer's output property you will get a string.  Since strings in VB are always UTF-16 thats what you get regardless of the encoding.  Since strings are always UTF-16 in VB there is no notion of them needing a BOM so that isn't included either.

The encoding and the BOM properties only affect how the writer will write the XML when an implementation of IStream is **assigned** to the output property.

Try modifying you code around the call to parse as follows:-

```
Dim oStream As ADODB.Stream
Set oStream =  New ADODB.Stream
oStream.Open
oStream.Type = adTypeBinary

wrt.output = oStream

rdr.parse xmlDoc

oStream.SaveToFile App.Path + "\saved.xml"
oStream.Close
```

This should generate the desired output.

Comment: Confirmed, I got the same result through another way.  It is important to set the output property *first*, before the other properties or you still won't get the BOM.

Comment: @nobugz: Yes good catch, assigning to the output property needs to happen before assigning the other properties.

Comment: "oStream.Type = adTypeBinary" in my VBA, but that did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: @OtherMichael: Tweaked my code accordingly I admit guessed at that constant, I don't have VB6 installed on the machine I'm currently using, I tested in VBScript.