# XML Spec and UTF-16

Tags: xml, unicode, w3c, utf-16, specifications

[Section 4.3.3](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#charencoding) and [Appendix F](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-guessing) of the [XML 1.0 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/) speak about [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16), the [byte order mark (BOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) in UTF-16 encoded data streams, and the XML encoding declaration.  From the information in those sections, it would seem that a byte order mark is required in UTF-16 documents.  But the summary chart in Appendix F gives a scenario where a UTF-16 input does not have a Byte order mark, but this scenario has an xml declaration.  According to section 4.3.3, a UTF-16 encoded document does not require an encoding declaration (and the XML declaration itself is optional in such a case).

Given this information, is a UTF-16 xml document with neither a BOM nor an XML declaration that also lacks externally provided encoding information considered well-formed if the rest of the document is?

Comment: Section 4.3.3 seems to say that it is not, but the appendix F chart serves to make this unclear.

Comment: Unicode never stipulated a *requirement* for a BOM.  It is the worst possible thing you could do to your customer, but the right to create files that can only be read correctly by your own app is a given.  It makes sure that you customer depends on you, good for business.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the Unicode 6.2 specification (page 99):

> The UTF-16 encoding scheme may or may not begin with a BOM. However, when there is no BOM, and in the absence of a higher-level protocol, the byte order of the UTF-16 encoding scheme is big-endian.

So a BOM is not required in a UTF-16 document. But there may be a "higher-level protocol" such as the XML specification to indicate what needs to be done for UTF-16 XML documents without BOM.

Section 4.3.3 in the XML 1.0 specification says:

> Entities encoded in UTF-16 MUST and entities encoded in UTF-8 MAY begin with the Byte Order Mark described by Annex H of [ISO/IEC 10646:2000], section 16.8 of [Unicode] (the ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE character, #xFEFF).

Let's get back to the above later. Appendix F describes approaches for detecting the character encoding in case a BOM isn't present. But I don't think that section is relevant for your question as you're asking whether a UTF-16 XML document without BOM and without XML declaration is "well-formed" and Appendix F is a non-normative part of the specification.

So, going back to the specification, a document is well-formed if "Taken as a whole, it matches the production labeled document." (Section 2.1). Reviewing `document` shows that the XML declaration is optional (this is also mentioned in Section 2.8). So it's possible to have a well-formed document without a XML declaration; this answers half of your question.

The other half is whether a UTF-16 XML document without XML declaration but also without BOM can still be well-formed. In Section 4.3.3 it says (emphasis mine):

> In the absence of information provided by an external transport protocol (e.g. HTTP or MIME), it is a fatal error for an entity including an encoding declaration to be presented to the XML processor in an encoding other than that named in the declaration, **or for an entity which begins with neither a Byte Order Mark nor an encoding declaration to use an encoding other than UTF-8**.

Based on this a UTF-16 XML document without BOM and without encoding declaration (which is part of the XML declaration) is not a well-formed document (because a fatal error violates wellformed-ness, see definition of well-formedness constraint in Section 1.2) in the absence of external information. This also matches what was said earlier in Section 4.3.3 about the requirement of a BOM for UTF-16.